# Call ejb3 existing in a module from a war in JBOSS as 7.1

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, jndi

I have a problem while trying to call my ejb3 existing in JBoss 7 module from my war file. Please have a look on following details-

Here is Local interface-

```
package com.uniteller.switchcore.cs.iface;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Local
public interface CSTimer {
     public boolean init(  );
}
```

EJB:

```
package com.uniteller.switchcore.cs.impl;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    public class CSTimerBean implements CSTimer {


        public CSTimerBean() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


        @Override
        public boolean init() {
    //Some log statements
    }
}
```

both interface and bean are in side the jboss as 7 module (JBOSS_HOME/modules/com.xxx.switch.main) within Switch.jar.

Now my problem is, I am trying to call it from a war (SwitchMain.war) but getting following exception-

```
12:50:41,593 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejb:/UFSwitch/CSTimerBean!com.uniteller.switchcore.cs.iface.CSTimer -- service jboss.naming.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try defining your own interface by adding 
**@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = “CSTimerBean “)** in your bean class. 
Refer to this link to validate how you are invoking the interface, it might be an issue in the way you are invoking http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/JNDI_Bindings.html

Comment: I'm sorry where exactly have you pasted the code? I was looking for the client invocation method.